# Including SUM and COUNT without accessing table twice

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm extracting `a`, `b` and `c` from `table_1`. Let's say, `a` represents a car model. 
Now I'd like to add from `table_2` the sum people paid for this car and also the number of people who own this car.

Is there a more elegant way to do this than I did? I don't like the fact that I 
access `table_2` twice and think that there must be an easier way.

I'd like to add that I work on an Oracle 11g database and the user I'm working with is not allowed to create views, procedures and the like.

```
select my_selection.*, 
      ( select sum(amount) 
          from table_2 t2 
         where t2.a = t1.a  ) as sum_buying_price, 
      ( select count(*) 
         from table_2 t2 
        where t2.a = t1.a ) as count_car_owners
from ( select a,
              b,
              c
         from table_1 t1
         ) my_selection
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `a b c` are unique, You can use this

`select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, sum(amount), count(*) 
   from table_1 t1
   left join table_2 t2 
     on t2.a = t1.a
  group by t1.a, t1.b, t1.c`

pay attention to `left join`, as if there are no records, inner join wouldn't return this row.

**Edit:** Sorry for another answer (but not a comment to Paparazzi's answer), haven't enough rep to comment yet.

**P.S.** While `count(*)` returns 0, `sum(amount)` returns `null`. Can be fixed with nvl:

```
nvl(sum(amount), 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am going to assume a, b, c are unique in table_1

```
select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, sum(amount), count(*) 
  from table_1 t1
  left join table_2 t2 
        on t2.a = t1.a  
group by t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine, I'm going to use this statement :)

Comment: As Razzka pointed out in another answer, this will not return the expected result if there is no "a" in table_2. If that is possible, you very likely want an outer join (as Razzka has shown).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, also to Razzka!

Comment: @OliverS. You mean the answer he copy pasted from me and added "left" rather than just leave a comment on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select t1.a, 
       t1.b, 
       t1.c, 
       sum_buying_price,
       count_car_owners
from table_1 t1
inner join
    ( select a, 
             sum(amount) as sum_buying_price, 
             count(*) as count_car_owners
      from table_2 
      group by a
    ) t2  on t1.a = t2.a
```

I have no oracle database to test against, and you didn't provide the relevant tables structure or sample data, so I can't really test it.

Comment: That's a huge improvement.  Although I now got a full table access on table_2, cost/bytes/cardinality are significantly reduced. I'll try to figure out if I can avoid the full table access. - Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how can I help beyond that, I'm not an Oracle guy, I work mostly with Sql Server. I can tell you that if a, b and c are unique in table_1 you better go with Paparazzi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
select my_selection.*, 
      ( select sum(amount) 
          from table_2 t2 
         where t2.a = my_selection.a  ) as sum_buying_price, 
      ( select count(*) 
         from table_2 t2 
        where t2.a = my_selection.a ) as count_car_owners
from ( select a,
              b,
              c
         from table_1
         ) my_selection
```

Comment: Did you mean something else? You just copied and pasted the OP's query. Not cool!

Comment: I make some changes.i think you can't see that.please check the queries.thank you.

Comment: I see you changed a table name to an inexistent one (so the query will throw an error), did you make any other changes? Anyway, the OP's only question was how to AVOID running the SUM in a subquery and then again COUNT in another subquery on the same table. Where did you solve that problem?